# How to detect the REQUEST_URI ALONG WITH ANCHOR TAG in a php script

Tags: php, query-string, anchor

One of my script is being called as

**script.php?l=addr#anchor**

I found, using SESSION **[REQUEST_URI]** or **QUERY_STRING**, gives **script.php?l=addr**

Is there a way to get the **#anchor** too using php?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The anchor is not usually available serverside. It is a guide to the browser.
If you really want to know what anchor is called, and you have control of the site you can add &anchor=anchor at the end of your url.

If you don't have control of the place where your script is called, I don't think you have much of a chance.

Regarding the post below:
It is true that you can use parse_url() to retrieve the anchor part of a given url.
The issue here is that you do not have access to the full url ( including anchors ) from php.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, can not be done with PHP, unless given directly to the link.
USE Javascript(Use Framework jQuery).

Example:

**CURRENT URL:** website.com/index/#my-id

**jQuery Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    url         : 'document.php',
    data        : { url : document.location.href },
    dataType    : 'json',
    success     : function( response )
    {
        if( response )
        {
            //this is a example... your code here
        }
    },
    error       : function( a , b )
    {
        //ops, error!
    }
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

    $id = preg_replace( '/(.*?)\#/i' , '' , $_GET['url'] );    //RETURN "my-id"
    echo $id;    //print $id
?>
```

Bye!!