# not getting link proper from query string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hello I have developed a demo application. my first html page looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickPdf() {
            window.location=("http://localhost:63320/WebForm1.aspx?url=http://localhost:63320/nestle/html5dctpro/index.html#Economic/Total-Group-Sales");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="clickPdf()" value="DownloadPdf" />
</body>
</html>
```

I have one aspx page it's look like

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var URL = Request.QueryString["url"];
    }
}
```

Now My Prob is I am getting `URL=http://localhost:63320/nestle/html5dctpro/index.html` rather then full url it's being cut due to # sign can anyone please tell me how can I get the full url.

Thanks

Comment: I think URL encoding will be required because `#` delimits URL

Comment: The location hash is available client side only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) in JavaScript. This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #` in the URI.

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function clickPdf() {
      var theURL = "http://localhost:63320/nestle/html5dctpro/index.html#Economic/Total-Group-Sales";
      window.location=("http://localhost:63320/WebForm1.aspx?url="+
                         encodeURIComponent(theURL));
   }
</script>
```

**Server Side** (no change required):

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var URL = Request.QueryString["url"];            
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET will not be able to directly give you the the hash (that is the bit after `#`), without being told by something else (like JavaScript).

This is because the browser is not telling the server what the hash is.

What you want to do can be done via JavaScript. (And JavaScript can access the hash, if necessary via `window.location.hash`.)

So if you really want to pass the hash to .NET, you will need to make JavaScript pass it via something else than a hash itself. Maybe another GET variable.

For example:

```
window.location=("http://localhost:63320/WebForm1.aspx?url=http://localhost:63320/nestle/html5dctpro/index.html&hash=Economic/Total-Group-Sales#hash=Economic/Total-Group-Sales");
```

(And even remove the original hash, if it has further reason to be there.)

Comment: hey what about escape function I have used it and it's working fine

Comment: @DhavalPatel If you use escape functions, things might go bad. The hash will be converted into `%23` and actually become an appended part of `index.html`. It is possible you run into `404 - file not found` issues. And also the hash will no longer be accessible on your current page as a hash. It will rather be given to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't use the good method.;o/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string : "RFC 3986 specifies that the query component of a URI is the part between the ? and the end of the URI or the character #".

Comment: [How to detect the REQUEST_URI ALONG WITH ANCHOR TAG in a php script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8744299/3678718)

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript `encodeURI` and decode back at the server level: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuri

Answer (score 1):

Well when you are sending data in querystring then simply replace such characters like

```
#,&
```

with theirn URL encode equivalent. In this case replace

```
# with %23
```

Just a demo:

```
var str = "http://localhost:63320/WebForm1.aspx?url=http://localhost:63320/nestle/html5dctpro/index.html#Economic/Total-Group-Sales");
var res = str.replace("#", "%28");
```